# Comparar 2 arrays com some() ou every()

Tags: javascript, node.js, javascript-eventos

Estou tentando fazer um exercício que compare se o array de objetos inseridos em uma função tem algum elemento igual ao array a seguir:

```
const gooUsers = [
    {id: 1},
    {id: 2},
    {id: 3}
];
```

A entrada da função poderia ser o array a seguir como exemplo:

```
const test = [
    {id: 2},
    {id: 1}
];
```

O resultado no caso acima seria true pra some() e false para every(), creio eu.

A função que consegui fazer até o momento:

```
const checkUsersValid = goodUsers => 
     (submittedUsers) =>{

         return goodUsers
            .some(value1=> submittedUsers
            .some(value2=> value1 === value2));
     }
```

Comment: Qual é o seu problema concretamente?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não entendi muito bem, mas acredito que seja isso que você quer,

```
goodUsers=[{id:1},{id:2},{id:3}];
const checkUsersValid= (submittedUsers) =>{

 return goodUsers
    .some(value1=> submittedUsers
    .some(value2=> Object.keys(value1)[0] === Object.keys(value2)[0] && Object.values(value1)[0] === Object.values(value2)[0]));
}
checkUsersValid([{id:1},{id:2}])
```